# Проблема с обращением к List<Object> из Main

Tags: java, list, коллекции, arraylist

Не могу из метода Main вызвать функции листа. Есть фигуры, которые мы можем запихивать в коробку. Коробка и является листом. Что не так? Помогите пожалуйста, люди добрые

Коробка:

```
import org.belsut.estryn.lessons.task02.figures.Figure;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Box {
    private List<Figure> box;

    public Box() {
        box = new ArrayList<Figure>();
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box box = new Box();

        PaperCircle paperCircle = new PaperCircle(5);

        box.add(paperCircle); //add подчеркивает красным. 
                              //подсказывает: "Создайте метод add в классе Box"
    }
}
```

Comment: Следуйте подсказке. Создайте метод.

Comment: В вашем классе Вох нет метода адд()

Comment: Коробка не является листом. Объекты класса `Box` содержат приватное поле, которое и является списком.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а как это исправить? Как сделать эту коробку именно листом? Просто сделать поле public?

Answer (score 1):

У вас в классе `Box` нет метода `add()`. Создайте метод `add()` в классе `Box`, либо создайте метод `getBox()`, возвращающий лист. Примеры реализации:

```
// класс Box
public void add(Figure figure) {
   box.add(figure);
}
// вызывайте этот метод также, как у вас в коде в вопросе
```

Или второй способ(более желательный):

```
// класс Box
public List<Figure> getBox() {
   return box;
}
// вот как  добавлять объекты
box.getBox().add(...);
```

Comment: этот вариант мне не подходит. Моя коробка должна являться листом. Я хочу к ней обращаться как к листу

Comment: @ВладиславЭстрин тогда `Box` должен наследовать `List`.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev тогда ведь придется переопределить все методы, иначе idea подчеркивает класс с наследованием

Comment: @ВладиславЭстрин ну наследуйте реализацию, `ArrayList` например.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev спасибо - это помогло

Comment: @ВладиславЭстрин упс, только увидел комментарии)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Необходимо класс Box унаследовать от ArrayList
Спасибо @Sergey Gornostaev

```
public class Box extends ArrayList {

    @Override
    public boolean add(Object o) {
        if (this.contains(o)) {
            return false;
        }
        return super.add(o);
    }
}
```

Comment: В этом случае вам не нужен `private List<Figure> box`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а как будет выглядеть класс?

Comment: Если не требуется расширять функционал `ArrayList`, то просто `public class Box<T> extends ArrayList<T> {}` Правда, становится непонятно зачем он тогда вообще нужен, почему просто не использовать `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev мне нужно будет переопределить метод, например add, т.к. по условию моей задачи я не могу добавить две одинаковые фигуры в ящик. Я явно делаю что-то не так, но не могу понять где я запутался)

Comment: Да, выглядит, как велосипедостроение. Вам проще создать новый вопрос, в тексте которого надо подробно описать задачу.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev спасибо, так и сделал) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/977484/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2-add-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0