# Переопределение методов add листа

Tags: java, list, коллекции, arraylist

Не могу переопределить методы add. Вернее могу, но они не работают так, как нужно. Суть задачи: У на есть фигуры (типа Figure) и коробка (ArrayList<>()). Фигуры мы добавляем в коробку. Нельзя добавить одну и ту же фигуру в коробку. Пытаюсь переопределить это в классе с моей коробкой - не получается.

Класс коробка:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Box extends ArrayList {
    private List<Figure> box;

    public Box() {
        box = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(Object o) {
        if (box.contains(o)){
            return false;
        }
        return super.add(o);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int index, Object element) {
        if (box.contains(element)){
            return;
        }
        super.add(index, element);
    }
}
```

В итоге из класса Main всё равно можно спокойно добавить 2 одинаковые фигуры в коробку. Что не так с моей коробкой?)

Вот класс Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box box = new Box();

        PaperCircle paperCircle = new PaperCircle(5);

        System.out.println(box.add(paperCircle));
        System.out.println(box.add(paperCircle));

        System.out.println(box.size());

    }
}
```

При выполнении видим:
true
true
2

А должно быть:
true
false
1

Comment: Требование наследовать `Box` от `ArrayList` явным образом определено в задании?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev нет, такого не написано в задании. Написано только что должна "уметь" коробка. А дальше я сам намудрил уже))

Comment: Так у ArrayList уже есть внутренне хранилище, вы в него добавляете как раз через super, а зачем то ещё создали List box и проверяете наличие элементов в нём, а не там, куда добавляете. Удалите его, а вместо box напишите this. И вообще, если нужны только уникальные элементы, то почему бы не использовать Set?

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon это будет звучать смешно, но мы его ещё не проходили)))) Ваше решение помогло. Спасибо. Я не понимал саму суть видимо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых

```
public class Box extends ArrayList<Figure> {
    @Override
    public boolean add(Figure figure) {
        if (this.contains(figure)){
            return false;
        }
        return super.add(figure);
    }
}
```

Во-вторых, лучше подойдёт не `ArrayList`, а [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).

Во-третьих, стоит реализовать в классе `Figure` [методы hash и equals](https://habr.com/ru/post/168195/).

Comment: Спасибо, я именно так и сделал уже. Подскажите, а можно ли сделать без наследования от ArrayList (просто создать в классе лист и прописать те методы, которые нам нужны) и есть ли в этом смысл? P.S. Кстати, в объявлении класса можно просто писать ArrayList { результат такой же @SergeyGornostaev

Comment: @ВладиславЭстрин конечно можно и очень даже имеет смысл.

Comment: я наверное так и сделаю) спасибо огромное за помощь. equals и hash я переопределил)